# Chai-http: sends 204 status instead of expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I have a problems with few test with chai. Here I created gist with my test file code https://gist.github.com/dulgeoion/56f90024ddc416abd3496d4d52dfb030

So, on last two test's I got this error `Uncaught AssertionError: expected 204 to equal 406` and `Uncaught AssertionError: expected 204 to equal 200`. I'm doing test's for the first time and can't get what the problem is.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because of the response status code you are getting in your API response.
Seems like your APIs are returning status code 204 while expected status code was 406. Same with second failure where you got 204 instead of 200.

Please check the API responses either by printing response in the console or by trying out APIs in postman.

Comment: Actually, I found that it is a problem with migrations, not with API, cause if I swap any tests, last two always will get 204 error

Comment: First 204 is not an error. It is a success response code where body is blank. Also, have tried running your tests via postman? Because it seems to me an issue with your API responses.